# How can I filter a file for lines containing a string in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: text-editing, sublime-text-2

I want to filter a file I'm editing in Sublime Text 2 for lines contain a certain string, if possible including regular expressions.

Consider the following file:

```
foo bar
baz
qux
quuux baz
```

When filtered for `ba`, the result should be:

```
foo bar
baz
quuux baz
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 is an extensible editor with a [Python API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html). You can create new commands (called *Plugins*) and make them available from the UI.

### Adding basic filtering TextCommand plugin

In Sublime Text 2, select *Tools » New Plugin* and enter the following text:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

def filter(v, e, needle):
    # get non-empty selections
    regions = [s for s in v.sel() if not s.empty()]
    
    # if there's no non-empty selection, filter the whole document
    if len(regions) == 0:
        regions = [ sublime.Region(0, v.size()) ]

    for region in reversed(regions):
        lines = v.split_by_newlines(region)

        for line in reversed(lines):
            if not needle in v.substr(line):
                v.erase(e, v.full_line(line))

class FilterCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        def done(needle):
            e = self.view.begin_edit()
            filter(self.view, e, needle)
            self.view.end_edit(e)

        cb = sublime.get_clipboard()
        sublime.active_window().show_input_panel("Filter file for lines containing: ", cb, done, None, None)
```

Save as `filter.py` in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User`

### Integration with UI

To add this plugin to the *Edit* menu, select *Preferences… » Browse Packages* and open the `User` folder. If a file called `Main.sublime-menu` doesn't exist, create it. Add or set the following text to that file:

```
[
    {
        "id": "edit",
        "children":
        [
            {"id": "wrap"},
            { "command": "filter" }
        ]
    }
]
```

This will insert the `filter` command call (essentially, `filter` is transformed to `FilterCommand().run(…)` for the plugin call and *Filter* for the menu label) just below the `wrap` command. See [step 11 here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin/) for a more detailed explanation why that is.

To assign a keyboard shortcut, open and edit the file `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` on OS X, or the equivalent for other systems, and enter the following:

```
[  
    {   
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "filter"
    }  
]
```

This will assign the shortcut <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to this command.

---

To make the command show up in the *Commands Palette*, you need to create a file named `Default.sublime-commands` (or edit an existing one) in the `User` folder. The syntax is similar to the menu file you just edited:

```
[
    { "caption": "Filter Lines in File", "command": "filter" }
]
```

Multiple entries (enclosed by curly brackets) need to be separated by commas.

### Behavior and UI integration screenshots

The command, as implemented, will filter all lines that are part of a selection (the entire lines, not just the selected parts), or, if no selection exists, the entire buffer, for a substring that is entered to the input field (default is the — possibly useless multi-line — clipboard) after the command is triggered. It can easily be extended to e.g. support regular expressions, or only leave lines *not* matching a certain expression.

#### Menu item

[image: Command in menu]

#### Commands palette entry

[image: Command with different label in Commands Palette]

#### Editor

[image: User entering text to filter file with]

[image: Result after executing the command]

### Adding support for Regular Expressions

To add support for regular expressions, use the following scripts and snippets instead:

`filter.py`:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, re

def matches(needle, haystack, is_re):
    if is_re:
        return re.match(needle, haystack)
    else:
        return (needle in haystack)

def filter(v, e, needle, is_re = False):
    # get non-empty selections
    regions = [s for s in v.sel() if not s.empty()]
    
    # if there's no non-empty selection, filter the whole document
    if len(regions) == 0:
        regions = [ sublime.Region(0, v.size()) ]

    for region in reversed(regions):
        lines = v.split_by_newlines(region)

        for line in reversed(lines):

            if not matches(needle, v.substr(line), is_re):
                v.erase(e, v.full_line(line))

class FilterCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        def done(needle):
            e = self.view.begin_edit()
            filter(self.view, e, needle)
            self.view.end_edit(e)

        cb = sublime.get_clipboard()
        sublime.active_window().show_input_panel("Filter file for lines containing: ", cb, done, None, None)

class FilterUsingRegularExpressionCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        def done(needle):
            e = self.view.begin_edit()
            filter(self.view, e, needle, True)
            self.view.end_edit(e)

        cb = sublime.get_clipboard()
        sublime.active_window().show_input_panel("Filter file for lines matching: ", cb, done, None, None)
```

`Main.sublime-menu`:

```
[
    {
        "id": "edit",
        "children":
        [
            {"id": "wrap"},
            { "command": "filter" },
            { "command": "filter_using_regular_expression" }
        ]
    }
]
```

`Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`:

```
[  
    {   
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+f"], "command": "filter"
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+shift+option+f"], "command": "filter_using_regular_expression"
    }
]
```

A second plugin command, *Filter Using Regular Expression* will be added below the *Filter* menu entry.

`Default.sublime-commands`:

```
[
    { "caption": "Filter Lines in File", "command": "filter" },
    { "caption": "Filter Lines in File Using Regular Expression", "command": "filter_using_regular_expression" }
]
```

Comment: Don't you want to publish this as a package one day?

Comment: @slhck Someone already did (with appropriate attribution), see NovicePhysicist's answer. From what I read in the code, it was improved quite a bit over this answer as well.

Comment: Cool, I didn't notice that!

Comment: What is that theme you have with the SublimeText that gives that nice colors? Or is it just changing the window color?

Comment: @pal4life: It's called *Solarized (Light)*. I think Sublime Text even ships with it. I might have installed an alternative one though, so the colors might not match exactly. Screenshots are on OS X, so that's where the window border and title bar are from.

Comment: Is there a way to get this working in ST3? The good thing with this above example is that there is no empty/folded lines between the result set making it much easier changing multiple lines in one go. This is not an option with FilterLines which has an empty/folded line between each result set

Answer (score 104):

There is also a *poor man's line filtering algorithm* (or is it lazy?):

1. **Select** string of interest
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to go into multi-cursor mode on all occurrences
3. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select entire line (on every cursor line)
4. Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave the search input field.
5. Copy-paste selection to another buffer.
6. (If needed) Remove the empty lines. E.g. by sorting lines and removing the empty ones or with `Edit -> Permute Lines -> Unique` and removing the remaining single line.

Comment: This is pretty much the simplest solution. Bravo!

Comment: Thank you! I prefer not having to install/learn another plugin for as much as possible - Alt+F3 is in my muscle memory so the above solution is actually not that far fetched for me.

Comment: You can replace Steps 3 and 4 with a single step: Ctrl+L.

Comment: Oh, thank you Andres! Will update the answer.

Comment: Nice simple solution! I would replace step 3 
from Ctrl-L
to Home , Shift-End
So there is no empty lines between occurences.

Comment: This changed my life for the better.  Nothing will ever be the same again.

Comment: for those on mac, replace step 2 with ctl + cmd + G, and step 3 with cmd + L - works great!

Comment: SuperUser indeed

Answer (score 55):

There's now a **plugin** for filtering lines: https://github.com/davidpeckham/FilterLines

It allows filtering and code folding based on strings or regular expressions.

[image: Sublime Text Filter Plugin by David Peckham]

Comment: Just installed this plugin - PERFECT for the job. Takes an existing file, lets you enter a filter phrase and puts the results in a new tab.

Comment: Agreed, until now I have only ever dreamed of having this sort of functionality in my text editor.

Comment: This plugin is really awesome!

Comment: Came here because a coworker mentioned something about "Keep Lines" for emacs and how useful it is. Didn't even know I needed this plugin, absolutely love it!

Answer (score 17):

You can use Sublime's built-in capabilities to do this in 3 to 7 key strokes (not including the regex to be matched).

### Step 1: Multi-select all matching lines

**Option 1: To multi-select all lines containing a substring**

1. Select the string of interest.
2. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to multi-select all occurences.
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Expand Selection to Line).

**Option 2: To multi-select all lines matching a regexp**

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Find drawer.
2. Make sure Regular Expression matching is enabled (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to toggle).
3. Type in the regular expression.
4. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to multi-select all matches.
5. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Expand Selection to Line).

### Step 2: Do something with those lines

**Option 1: To get rid of all lines that *are not* selected**

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to replace selection with the matching lines.

**Option 2: To get rid of all lines that *are* selected**

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Delete Line).

**Option 3: To extract selected lines to a new file**

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open a new file.
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

Comment: This is an excellent list of commands!

Comment: Super, but is there way to remove blank lines after paste?

Comment: @SergeySenkov Sure! (1) Hit Ctrl+F to open the Find drawer. (2) Make sure Regular Expression matching is enabled (Alt+R to toggle). (3) Type in "\n\n+" (matches two or more consecutive newlines). (4) Hit Alt+Enter to multi-select all matches. (5) Hit Enter to replace all matches with a single newline.