# How can I edit file permissions (e.g. make script files executable) from within Sublime Text 2?

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2, text-editing

When writing e.g. shell scripts, I want to change their permissions (primarily the *executable* permission) from within Sublime Text 2.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is a general purpose permissions editing command for the file currently being edited. For a more detailed explanation on plugins and editing the Sublime Text 2 menu, see [this post](https://superuser.com/a/452190/22317).

It will add a *Change Mode* command in the *Edit* menu. When selected, the user is asked to enter a valid argument string to chmod (e.g. `u+rwx` or `755`; default is the currently set 4 digit octal permissions string like `0644`), that is then applied to the file being edited.

[image: Screenshot of input panel]

Select *Tools » New Plugin*, insert the following content and save as `chmod.py` in `~/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/`:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, subprocess

def chmod(v, e, permissions):
    subprocess.call( [ "chmod", permissions, v.file_name() ] )

def stat(filename):
    proc = subprocess.Popen( [ "stat", "-f", '%Mp%Lp', filename ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
    return str(proc.communicate()[0]).strip()

class ChangeModeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        if sublime.platform() != 'osx':
            return

        fname = self.view.file_name()

        if fname == None:
            sublime.message_dialog("You need to save this buffer first!")
            return

        perms = stat(fname)

        def done(permissions):
            chmod(self.view, edit, permissions)

        sublime.active_window().show_input_panel(
            "permissions to apply to the file " + fname + ": ", perms, done, None, None)
```

To insert a menu item for this command, add the following to `~/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Main.sublime-menu`, merging with existing file contents if the file already exists:

```
[
    {
        "id": "edit",
        "children":
        [
            {"id": "wrap"},
            { "command": "change_mode" }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Is it necessary to restrict to OSX, or could that condition be loosened up to include linux, or even changed to "not windows" ?

Comment: @DarthAndroid I don't have a GUI Linux at the moment to test it with, so I went most restrictive in both code and question tags. Other than that, I see no reason to exclude Linux. `if sublime.platform() == 'windows':` will probably work as well.

Answer (score 3):

It basically works under Linux too, but the `stat` command works differently and shows numerous information that is not needed.

```
stat -c %a filename
```

will do instead and returns something like '644'.