# Sublime Text 2 - insert breaks to match current wrapping?

Tags: sublime-text-2, newlines

Is there an automated way to insert line breaks at every point where the text is currently wrapping?  After this operation, no lines should be wrapped, but it should look visually identical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a plugin for this. Select *Tools » New Plugin…* and enter the following script:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class WrapLinesExCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        wrap_column = 0

        if self.view.settings().get('word_wrap') == False:
            # wrapping is disabled, do nothing
            return

        if self.view.settings().get('wrap_width') == 0:
            # compute wrap column from viewport width
            wrap_column = int(self.view.viewport_extent()[0] / self.view.em_width())
        else:
            wrap_column = self.view.settings().get('wrap_width')

        e = self.view.begin_edit()
        rewrap(self.view, e, wrap_column)
        self.view.end_edit(e)

def rewrap(v, e, column):
    # 0-indexed current line
    current_line_no = 0

    # RHS expression is line count, can change whenever we create a new one
    while current_line_no < v.rowcol(v.size())[0] + 1:
        # where current line drawing starts
        current_line_coords = v.text_to_layout(v.text_point(current_line_no, 0))

        # rightmost character drawn in current viewport
        textpos = v.layout_to_text((v.em_width() * (column), current_line_coords[1]))

        # physical line boundaries as absolute text positions
        current_line = v.line(textpos)

        if textpos < current_line.b:
            # the current line spans multiple rows, so insert a newline at the wrap column

            textpos = v.layout_to_text((v.em_width() * (column), current_line_coords[1]))
            next_line_indent = v.text_to_layout(textpos+1)[0]

            # TODO why -1?
            next_line_indent_chars = int(next_line_indent/(v.em_width()))-1
            # determine how to indent the following line based on how wide the wrapping indents and what the current tab/spaces settings are
            if v.settings().get('translate_tabs_to_spaces') and v.settings().get('use_tab_stops'):
                next_line_indent_chars = next_line_indent_chars / v.settings().get('tab_size')
                next_line_indent_string = '\t' * next_line_indent_chars
            else:
                next_line_indent_string = ' ' * next_line_indent_chars

            # insert newline and spacing at wrap column (sublime hides actual line endings from editor, therefore it's always LF)
            v.insert(e, textpos, '\n' + next_line_indent_string)
        else:
            # only continue to the next line if we didn't edit the current line
            current_line_no = current_line_no + 1
```

Save e.g. as `wrap_lines_ex_command.py` in the default (`User`) directory.

To make this accessible from the menu bar, select the *Browse Packages…* menu item, navigate to the `User` folder, and edit `Main.sublime-menu` (creating it if necessary) as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/452190/22317) so it contains text like e.g. the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "edit",
        "children":
        [
            {"id": "wrap"},
            {"command": "wrap_lines_ex", "caption": "Wrap All Lines"}
        ]
    }
]
```

### Screenshots

Before:

[image: Screenshot before]

After:

[image: Screenshot after]

Of course, in this case, due to comments being wrapped as well, the code will no longer work. But that's behavior as design per the question.

Answer (score 3):

Years later, there are ready-made packages (plug-ins) for this kind of thing.  They might not satisfy your request exactly (to match the current wrapping shown in your window), but you can set which column you want to wrap at in their preferences.

## Sublime-Wrap-Plus

**[GitHub page](https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus)**

### Installation

1. Open `Sublime Text 2 or 3`.
2. Press `command-shift-p` (Mac OS X) or `ctrl-shift-p` (Windows) to open the `Command Palette`, type "install," and select the option to `Install Package Control`.
3. Open the `Command Palette` again, type "install" again, and select the option to `Install a Package`.
4. Start typing and then select `sublime-wrap-text`.

### Usage

1. Select the text in question.
2. Press `command+alt+q` (Mac OS X) or `alt+q` (Windows).

See the GitHub page for more usage nuances and how to set preferences.

### Demo

**Before**

[image]

**After** (I just highlighted all of the text and hit alt+q)

[image]

Another similar package is **Sublime-Wrap-Statement**

[GitHub page](https://github.com/shagabutdinov/sublime-wrap-statement)

I have not tried this one myself, but you can give it a try if you like.

Comment: aah, this works like charm, have been searching a lot for a couple of days...

Answer (score 1):

*Account too young to add as a comment

but wanted to add a 2021 update to [MarredCheese's excellent 2017 Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1198780/1175959) found above.*

## To install the first package MarredCheese mentioned:

**GitHub**:  https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus
**Sublime Package Name**: Wrap Plus

**Step 1.** Still works, pasting from original post:

1. Open Sublime

**Step 2.** Still works, pasting from original post:

2. Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> (Mac OS X) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> (Windows) to open the `Command Palette`, type "install," and select the option to `Install Package Control`.

**Step 3.** is minorly inaccurate.
In case the syntax changed here is what works in 2021:

**Step 3. (Original):**

- Open the `Command Palette again`, type "install" again, and select the option to `Install a Package`.

**Step 3. (Revised for 2021):**

- instead of typing `Install a Package` type either:

  - `Install Package` or
  - `Package Control: Install Package`
  - Note: "Package Control: Advanced Install Package" is useful,
    but not necessary for this recipe.

**Step 4.** no longer works.

**Step 4. (Original):**

- Start typing and then select `sublime-wrap-text`.

**Step 4. (Revised for 2021):**

- Type `Wrap Plus` into the Install Package dropdown
  (You will see https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus in the details of this entry)

## To install the second package MarredCheese mentioned at the bottom of their Answer:

**GitHub:** https://github.com/shagabutdinov/sublime-wrap-statement
**Sublime Package Name:** WrapStatement

Follow the same steps in the last section, but for **Step 3.** type `WrapStatement` instead (no space).
(You will see https://github.com/shagabutdinov/sublime-wrap-statement in the details of this entry in the `Install Package` dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it would appear that this feature is not included in Sublime Text 2's preferences (you can see for yourself in Default/Preferences.sublime-settings). It is possible to use a configuration option like`"line_padding_bottom": 4` (where 4 is the number of pixels you want beneath each line) for reading clarity on all lines, but it is not possible to selectively apply different line padding depending on whether or not the line is wrapped.

You may wish to submit a feature request [on Sublime Text 2's forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=4). I know I would appreciate this functionality as well, if it's reasonable to implement.