# How to open file using only keyboard in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

How do I open a file using only keyboard in Sublime Text 2/3?

Looking for equivalent of `<Esc>:e /path/to/file` from Vim.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On OS X, Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to open the file browser.

Then, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> allows you to enter the name of the folder to go to.

[image: Screenshot of file dialog]

Finally, just type the file name (or a unique prefix) to select the file you want. You can also navigate using the arrow keys.

---

### Plugin for opening files by name

The following plugin allows you to type a file name and have it opened in Sublime Text 2. It should work on any OS.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

def open_file(window, filename):
    window.open_file(filename, sublime.ENCODED_POSITION)

class OpenFileByNameCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        fname = self.window.active_view().file_name()
        if fname == None:
            fname = ""

        def done(filename):
            open_file(self.window, filename)

        self.window.show_input_panel(
            "file to open: ", fname, done, None, None)
```

This allows you to encode a position in that file in the file name:

- `/path/to/file:42` will open the file and go to line 42
- `/path/to/file:42:23` will open the file and go to line 42, column 23

#### Selecting a file:

[image: Screenshot 1]

#### After selection:

[image: Screenshot 2]

For information how plugins work and how you can integrate this in the UI, [see this answer](https://superuser.com/a/452190/22317).

Comment: Alt + D highlights the address bar in windows file explorer (windows 10), in case you're not able to do Cmd + PoopGlitter + G. From there, the address bar allows tab completion and will go straight to your file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the first suggestion for OSX, just what I needed =-D

Answer (score 50):

Why don't you just use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>? (`Goto -> Goto anything`)

Comment: this only works in the context of a project

Comment: memeLab - it works without a project too in Sublime Text 2. Cmd+P on Mac.

Comment: infinite upvote to this answer. It saved me lot of time for scrolling the list of many files.  Thanks buddy

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 11):

[Sublime Files](https://github.com/al63/SublimeFiles)  Sublime Text 2 plugin for keyboard driven file navigation. It is more less like Emacs file opening interface

Take a look at [Sublime-File-Navigator](https://github.com/belike81/Sublime-File-Navigator) plugin it is more VIM-ish

Answer (score 8):

I recently wrote a plugin, iOpener, that will open files from path using completion, directory listings and history. It also sensibly opens folders by adding the into the side bar of a new window.

I tried to emulate the functionality of emacs were possible.

https://github.com/rosshemsley/iOpener

(I know this question is for ST2. I could always back-port the code if there were enough demand. Though I suspect most people use ST3 now.)

Answer (score 3):

Verified on ST3.1.1, Build 3176. This should work without any plugin.

To open a file which is not part of the project, for example ~/.bashrc:

On Ubuntu, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to get to the file open dialog, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to get a line for writing the file name. This also works for hidden files.

On MacOS, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>.

For project files, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> respective <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be an answer to your question, but a viable workaround imho: go to a terminal and type:

`subl <path-to-file>`

I always have terminals at hand anyway :)