# Is there a way to "Execute and update '# => ' markers" in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: textmate, ruby, sublime-text-2

This is my most favourite feature from ruby bundle in TextMate. Unfortunately, I can't find how to do the same in ST2. It still inserts the marker when you press TAB after the `#` symbol, so, I hope, the ability to run ruby code and update such markers is there, but is well hidden.

For non-users of TextMate: let's assume we have typed this code

```
a = 10
b = 30
a + b # =>
```

Then, upon pressing a shortcut (ctrl+cmd+shift+E by default), textmate executes this code and inserts value of corresponding lines after `# =>` markers. In this instance, the result will look like this:

```
a = 10
b = 30
a + b # => 40
```

It's super handy for quickly trying out things and posting nice snippets to stackoverflow. Now I need ST2 to do this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TextMate uses [rcodetools](http://rubygems.org/gems/rcodetools) to achieve this. From its bundle editor for the command *Execute and Update ‘# =>’ Markers*:

> `"${TM_RUBY}" -r "${TM_SUPPORT_PATH}/lib/ruby1.9/add_1.8_features.rb" -- "$TM_BUNDLE_SUPPORT/vendor/rcodetools/bin/xmpfilter"`

`xmpfilter` comes with the `rcodetools` gem and can be run standalone.

> `$ sudo gem install rcodetools`
>   `[...]`
>   `$ export RUBYLIB=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ruby/user-gems/1.8/gems/rcodetools-0.8.5.0/lib/`
>   `$ echo "1+5 # => " | ruby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ruby/user-gems/1.8/gems/rcodetools-0.8.5.0/bin/xmpfilter`
>   `1+5 # => 6`

Now you just need to wrap these commands in a Sublime Text 2 plugin, passing the current document as input and replace it with output. You can find general information on how to create and integrate plugins with Sublime Text 2 [in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/452189/how-can-i-filter-a-file-for-lines-containing-a-string-in-sublime-text-2/452190#452190).

Here's the plugin code custom to this problem, for the environment shown above:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, subprocess

class ExecuteAndUpdateRubyMarkers(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        r = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
        text = self.view.substr(r)

        s = subprocess.Popen(
            [
                '/usr/bin/env',
                'RUBYLIB=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ruby/user-gems/1.8/gems/rcodetools-0.8.5.0/lib',
                'ruby',
                '/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/lib/ruby/user-gems/1.8/gems/rcodetools-0.8.5.0/bin/xmpfilter'
            ],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out = s.communicate(text)
        if s.returncode != None and s.returncode != 0:
            sublime.message_dialog("There was an error: " + out[1])
            return

        viewlines = self.view.lines(r)
        outlines = out[0].split('\n')
        for i in range(0, len(viewlines)):
            self.view.replace(edit, viewlines[i], outlines[i])
```

Before:

[image: Screenshot]

After:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I wonder, why there's no such plugin already? :) Thanks for the excellent answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Now there is.

Comment: thanks man, you're awesome! Although you eliminated this one opportunity to learn, I won't complain :)

Comment: Daniel, I am having problems executing the plugin code you have posted.  I am able to run the standalone example just fine.  How are you executing the command from within ST2?  Thanks

Comment: @AGS Please be more specific about what the problem is, and make sure to read the linked answer explaining how to set up plugins to ST2.

Comment: @DanielBeck, thanks, I have read that thread, and have built a few, simple plugins for my own use.  However, I am unsure how to execute plugins who's class does not use the "_Something_ Command" naming scheme.

Comment: @AGS Nice find, I didn't even notice that. Feel free to add the `Command` class name suffix. It just worked for me in ST2, version 2.0.1 build 2217. I specify the command in `User/Main.sublime-menu` as follows: `{"command": "execute_and_update_ruby_markers", "caption": "Execute and Update Ruby # => Markers"}`

Comment: Excellent @DanielBeck, works like a charm.  You're right, no need to ad `Command` in this case.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, thanks to Daniel Beck for his solution as it works wonderfully and was just what I was looking for.

#### Edit 18 March 2013:

I've made this into a Sublime package called **Ruby Markers**. The package includes the code discussed in this topic as well as a few other things not discussed (like OS handling [I'm looking at you windows], unicode support, rvm and rbenv support). It is available via **Package Manager** or at https://github.com/mmims/sublime-text-2-ruby-markers.